# render text file and change object's properties

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, render

i want to generate the output of an asp.net page by reading a text file, get the controls out of the text, change te properties of these controls, render it and displaying it.

so for example, the text file may contain:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <sys:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="empty1"></sys:Label>
        <sys:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="empty2"></sys:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

after reading the text, i would like to change the properties of the sys:label controls. After that, the text will be rendered, and displayed.

Problem is, how can i reach these controls ?

Comment: Why can't you simply use the standard `.aspx` file extension and code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

You could to create those text files as ASCX files, load them with `Page.LoadControl` and reach it's inner controls with `Page.FindControl`.